# Add not relevant column to group by script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my sample table and values:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
[Id]     BIGINT  NOT NULL  DEFAULT(0),
[VId]    BIGINT  NOT NULL  DEFAULT(0),
[Level]  INT     NOT NULL  DEFAULT(0)
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [VId], [Level]) VALUES (100, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [VId], [Level]) VALUES (101, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [VId], [Level]) VALUES (102, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [VId], [Level]) VALUES (103, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [VId], [Level]) VALUES (104, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [VId], [Level]) VALUES (105, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [VId], [Level]) VALUES (106, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [VId], [Level]) VALUES (107, 4, 2);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [VId], [Level]) VALUES (108, 4, 3);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [VId], [Level]) VALUES (109, 4, 4);
```

So at now I use this script:

```
SELECT 
    [T].[VId], MAX ([T].[Level]) AS [MaxLevel]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Test] AS [T]
GROUP BY 
    [T].[VId];
```

And it returns:

```
VId    MaxLevel
1      3
2      1
3      2
4      4
```

But I need `Id` column also and I can't add it to Group by script, I need the following values:

```
VId    MaxLevel   Id
1      3          102
2      1          103
3      2          105
4      4          109
```

What is your suggestion?

Also The following values is enough **The Id's With Max(Level) in any VId** :

```
Id
102
103
105
109
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use joining with the same table by VId column

something like this:

```
SELECT [T].[VId], [T].[MaxLevel], [T1].[Id]
FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [T1] JOIN
  (SELECT [T].[VId], MAX ([T].[Level]) AS [MaxLevel]
    FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [T]
    GROUP BY [T].[VId]) AS [T] 
ON [T1].[VId] = [T].[VId]
AND [T1].[Level] = [T].[MaxLevel]
ORDER BY [T].[VId];
```

the result will be:

```
VId MaxLevel  Id
1   3         102
2   1         103
3   2         105
4   4         109
```

Comment: Your script returns all the 10 rows, like `Select * From [Test]`

Comment: It lacks `and [T1].[Level] = [T].[MaxLevel]` in join conditions part.

Comment: Try updated one, I have added where condition for making sure that maxlevel is selected

Comment: It this case putting it in `where` clause or `join` conditions works same way but for clarity I'd put it in `join` part because this is the condition that you are using to join tables. This is the way I think and see this query - my interpretation. There are many ways to get the same result.

Answer (score 4):

A 2008 take on the question, since that's what you're working with:

```
declare @Test table
(
[Id]            BIGINT      NOT NULL    DEFAULT(0),
[VId]           BIGINT      NOT NULL    DEFAULT(0),
[Level]         INT         NOT NULL    DEFAULT(0)
);

INSERT INTO @Test ([Id], [VId], [Level])
VALUES (100, 1, 1),(101, 1, 2),(102, 1, 3),(103, 2, 1),(104, 3, 1),
(105, 3, 2),(106, 4, 1),(107, 4, 2),(108, 4, 3),(109, 4, 4);

;With Numbered as (
    select *,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY VId ORDER BY [Level] desc) as rn
from @Test)
select VId,Level,Id from Numbered where rn=1
```

Note that (as with the other solutions) this will output multiple rows per `VId` if there are two rows with the same maximum level. If you don't want that, switch `RANK()` to `ROW_NUMBER()` and an arbitrary one will win - or if you want a specific winner in the case of a tie, add that condition into the `ORDER BY` of the window function.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
WITH LastLevels AS
(
SELECT 
    [T].[VId] AS [VID], 
    MAX ([T].[Level]) AS [MaxLevel]

FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [T]
GROUP BY [T].[VId]
)

SELECT [LastLevels].[VID],[LastLevels].[MaxLevel], [Te].[Id]
FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [Te]
INNER JOIN [LastLevels]
ON [LastLevels].[VID]=[Te].[VId]
AND [LastLevels].[MaxLevel]=[Te].[Level]
ORDER BY [LastLevels].[VID];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, [VId], [MaxLevel] From
(
    SELECT 
        [T].[VId], MAX ([T].[Level]) AS [MaxLevel]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Test] AS [T]
    GROUP BY 
        [T].[VId]
)K
INNER JOIN [Test] T on T.[VId] = K.[VId] and T.[Level] = K.MaxLevel
```